# Comparing 'key answer' and 'answers' DataFrame in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows

I have this main **df1**:

```
Name | Course | Q_1 | Q_2 | ... | Q_60
John |  Phys  |  A  |  C  | ... |  D 
Karen|  Math  |  C  |  C  | ... |  E
 ... |  ...   | ... | ... | ... | ...
```

(~1200 names)

The key answer for reference is **df2**:

```
1   2   3   4   ...   60
A | C | C | E | ... | D
```

I want to compare **df1** with **df2** to answer questions of this type:

- **Which** questions did the students answer correctly?
- How many students got Q_3, Q_4, Q_5 and Q_10 right?

I've already tried to simply do conditional compare but this only gives me a np.array of booleans: is it possible to index the position of **True**/**False** matches to any given answer, returning something like:

**df3**:

```
Name | Course | Q_1 | Q_2 | ... |Q_60
John |  Phys  |True |True | ... |True
Karen|  Math  |False|True | ... |False
...........
```

And then make a conditional count of the *True* matches storing its position to get the solution?

Comment: Can you share what you have done so far and what you think will be a potential answer. We will review and provide you comments that lead you in the right direction.

Comment: I have a DataFrame with 4 sheets: two of them composes the answers given by the students, resulting 60 answers for each of them (**30 pre-test + 30 pos-test, but the test itself is the same**!!); the 3rd sheet is the key answer table, whose 30 correct answers must serve as guide to compare the individual's responses (the 4rd is just storing calculations). I'm stuck on comparing the student's answers with the 3rd sheet in a way that should be possible to locate WHICH (specifically) of them were correct.

Comment: I've already managed to calculate the **number** of right answers simply 'if comparing' ('==' operator), like: right_answers = np.array(data[ids_answer] == np.array(key_answer); but no idea how to store these guys keeping the right position on the dataframe (**df1**) to future checking (the focus, again, is the 2 questions I've fixed on the post). Anyway, thks in advance, any suggest could help!

Answer (score 0):

Use `add_preffix` and `eq`:

```
t=df2.add_prefix('Q_').iloc[0]
df1.set_index(['Name','Course']).eq(t,1).reset_index()
```

---

**Example**

With dummy data:

```
print(df1)
   Name Course Q_1 Q_2 Q_3
0   John   Phys   A   C   D
1  Karen   Math   C   C   E

print(df2)
   1  2  3
0  A  C  C

t=df2.add_prefix('Q_').iloc[0]
df1.set_index(['Name','Course']).eq(t,1).reset_index()

    Name Course    Q_1   Q_2    Q_3
0   John   Phys   True  True  False
1  Karen   Math  False  True  False
```

Comment: Didn't work: it justs adds 60 new columns with the new 'Q_[number]' index to df1 and output value goes all to "false", and this error appears:  "FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  res_values = method(rvalues)"

Comment: The **reset_index()** also didn't apply very well: the indices are messing up like putting Q_9 in the end, 'cause it appears to not see the composite numbers _e.g._ '53', '78' or '25', instead '5' '3', '7' '8' and so on... Anyway, thks for the answer.